# Trigonometric identities: harmonic form, negative statements

Tags: trigonometry

Find the min and max of these expressions and state smallest non-negative value of θ for which each occurs: 
1) 10 - 2sinθ + cosθ 
2) 1/((7 - 2cosθ + sqrt(5)sinθ))

1)
Harmonic form: R[sin(θ+α) = sinθcosα + cosθsinα] 
Rcosα = 2, Rsinα = 1 
R = 5 
tanα = 1/2, α = 26.6⁰ 
f(θ) = 10 - sqrt(5)sin(θ + 26.6⁰) 
max at sinθ = 90⁰, θ = 63.4⁰, max value = 10 - sqrt(5) 
min at sinθ = 270⁰, θ = 243.3⁰, min value = 10 + sqrt(5)

The solution booklet indicates 
10 + sqrt(5) at 296.6⁰ 
10 - sqrt(5) at 116.6⁰

2)
using Rcos(θ-α) I get 
1 / ((7 - 3cos(θ - 48.2⁰)) 
[rest omitted]

The solution booklet indicates 
1/4 at 311.8⁰ 
1/10 at 131.8⁰

I'm thinking that the negative statement is throwing me off in both cases 
1) -2sinθ + cosθ) 
2) -2cosθ + sqrt(5)sinθ

Any guidance is much appreciated

Comment: Here's the [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't provide the direct solution but it will help you.

$\begin{align}
y& = a{\sin x}+ b{\cos x}\\
y&=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}{\sin x}+\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}{\cos x}\right)
\end{align}$

Let $\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}={\cos \phi}$, then $\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}={\sin\phi}$.

$\begin{align}
y&=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}({\sin x}{\cos \phi}+{\sin \phi}{\cos x})\\
y&=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\left({\sin (x+\phi)}\right)
\end{align}$

$\begin{align}
-1 &\le {\sin (x+\phi)} &\le 1\\
-\sqrt{a^2+b^2}&\le \sqrt{a^2+b^2}{\sin (x+\phi)}&\le \sqrt{a^2+b^2}\\
-\sqrt{a^2+b^2}&\le \qquad\qquad y &\le \sqrt{a^2+b^2}
\end{align}$

Hence, the minimum value of$y$ is $-\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ and maximum value is $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$.